# How I find the matrix for this equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have an equation that is:

Q*Z=Z-E,

in which Q is a n*n matrix, Z is a n x 1 vector and E is a nx1 vector. If I know Z and E how I can find Q? In other words, how I get rid of the Z at left side of the equation?

Thank you,

Paulo

Comment: Solve, Simplify, FullSimplify

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help: $QZ = Z-E$ is equivalent to $(Q-I)Z = -E$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Now you have to create a matrix that will map one vector to another.

Take a diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal $d_i = -e_i/z_i$ (assuming $z_i \neq 0$) and it will do. If some $z_i = 0$, make a work-around using off-diagonal entries.

Then, $Q = D+I$.

Comment: @Paulo no problem.